# How do I decide which question to put where?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

How do I decide which question to put where between [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) and [unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)?

I have posted [a question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198079/problem-in-redirecting-standard-input-and-output) with `mysql`, `redirect`, `input` and `output` tags in [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), but I was confused where to put it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, when confused read the FAQ:

- [Unix and Linux FAQ](https://unix.stackexchange.com/faq),
- [AskUbuntu FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq)

It's not unthinkable that a question is suitable for more than one sites, in which case read their FAQs a second time and post in the one that feels a bit more suitable. If it's a good question, you shouldn't worry much about asking it at the wrong site, we can migrate questions automatically. If it's a bad question, well...

Now Unix and Linux and AskUbuntu [overlap a little bit more](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/unix-and-ubuntu-why-both/) than any two other sites would, and I *think* your question would be equally appropriate in either one. Personally I'd go with Unix and Linux, because I don't see anything Ubuntu specific in your question, but that doesn't necessarily mean it's off topic on AskUbuntu. In fact, it's already getting good answers.

Comment: thanks. I'll read the FAQs.

Comment: @HussainTamboli Also please note that every site has it's own Meta, you could have asked this on [Meta AskUbuntu](http://meta.askubuntu.com/), or [Meta Unix & Linux](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/). Meta Stack Overflow is more for Stack Overflow specific issues and issues that apply to the whole Stack Exchange network.

Comment: yes. didn't know that. Also not related to this question but are '@HussainTamboli' and '@hussain-tamboli' same; will I get notified on somebody else's comment when you put '@HussainTamboli'. I have 'hussain-tamboli' in my address bar/inbox, is it..

Comment: @HussainTamboli You only get notified for `@comments` when you've already participated in a comment thread, for example you wouldn't have gotten a notification for my earlier comment if you hadn't posted a comment prior to that. If you are already part of a comment thread (posted at least one comment under a post) then `@hus` is enough to generate a notification for you.